# How to resize AVPlayer width and height in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avplayer

I am using `AVKit` to play a video from url and the video is playing without any issue. I created a `PlayerViewClass` to assign player to the view.

**PlayerViewClass.swift**

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation


class PlayerViewClass: UIView {

override static var layerClass: AnyClass {

    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}

var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
    return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
}

var player: AVPlayer? {
    get {
        return playerLayer.player
    }

    set {
        playerLayer.player = newValue
    }
}

}
```

And I used it in `cellForItemAt` method in my `ViewController`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "videoCell", for: indexPath) as? VideoCollectionCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

    let videoUrl = URL(string: "file.mp4")

    let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl!)
    cell.playerView.playerLayer.player = avPlayer
    cell.playerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 352, height: 180) // it is not resizing
    cell.playerView.player?.play()
    return cell
}
```

I don't understand how can I resize my Player to the whole cell `myCell` is of height and width:-

```
CGSize(width: 352, height: 180)
```

**CollectionViewCell** class:-

```
class VideoCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var playerView: PlayerViewClass!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}
}
```

Please help.

[image]

Comment: can you share a sample code so i can try

Comment: this is all i have done to play video

Answer (score 1):

The code is wrong. Every view has a layer.

While it's layer is CALayer , not AVPlayerLayer.

```
class PlayerViewClass: UIView {

override static var layerClass: AnyClass {

    return AVPlayerLayer.self
}

var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer {
    return layer as! AVPlayerLayer
}
```

---

You are using `CGRect`,

`cell.playerView.frame= CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 352, height: 180)`

this is `CGSize`

`CGSize(width: 352, height: 180)`

[image]

Comment: I am using `CGSize` at both place

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
extension yourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        // your code here
        //width and height as per your requirement
        return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you,
thanks.

Comment: if i use use  my code here it will give this error ``Use of unresolved identifier 'playerView'` is there any method i can use ? :(

Comment: @wings can you describe where you show this error and can upload a image

Comment: you are telling me to write my player view code in this method.. but it is showing error

Comment: @wings whole things to as per your cellForItem just add this method for sizing you cell.

Comment: I don't understand can you give the example

Comment: @wings use cellForItem as per dengAngo code and add this method

Comment: @wings I will try with demo

Comment: for reference i used this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3wwI1NDeKc you can check here